# How to stop and again recall setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add setInterval functionality in my project, the
functionality setInterval calls first when window loads and then when
we click on specific button setInterval should be clear. But the
problem is we need to again recall the setInterval function and here
code is not working, code is here:

```
var inter_count=0;
var int = setInterval(function(){doThis(); },4000);

function doThis(){
    if(inter_count <= 9){
        //function one();
        inter_count++;
    }
    else if(inter_count <= 19){     
        //function two();
        inter_count++;
    }

}

$(".main").click(function(){
   clearInterval(int);  
});

$(".strt").click(function(){
    int = setInterval(function(){doThis(); },4000);
//I need to again call here setInterval but it won't work

});
```

Is there any problem with my code

Comment: does your console log any errors?

Comment: Why do you call `doThis` in an anonymous function? You can simply do `setInterval(doThis, 4000)`.

Comment: Why does calling `setInterval` again not work?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsbin.com/ovAxOhO/1/edit . Perhaps you have a typo in your `.strt` selector?

Comment: check with my code is there any issue , doThis is just for example here. Client wants this functionality

Comment: your link is not working here once again check @Tibos

Comment: It works for me, but you need to enable the CONSOLE tab

Comment: I can't check with your code because you didn't post enough of it to test on. Furthermore, i won't check with your code because i think you should do that, not me. You already have a working sample that is quite close to what you posted and you can figure out at the very least where the problem is from it. Also, you mention that the "link is not working" but you fail to provide useful information as to in what way it is not working: 404 error? code not working as expected? other error?

Comment: what's the specific error? Realize that as you coded it, if you click more than once on start interval link, you'd only be able to stop the last interval fired, but previous ones keep running